# Using VBA code to move data from an invoice to a sales summary page

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am creating a database for a friend of mine. She owns a small shop where people can purchase artisan pieces. I have created a Artisan list, and inventory list. on 2 sheets
then I have an invoice list that calls data from the inventory list based on an item code ( using Vloolup) and also applies the Artisan's 2 letter identification.
I then have a VBA formula which moves the data from each invoice to a Sales sheet that holds the data from each sale, even after the invoice is cleared.
This is the code I am using to transfer the data from each invoice to the "Sales" sheet.

I have included a copy of the invoice page so you can see where my code is pulling from

[image]

CODE:

```
Sub SavingSalesData()
Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long

  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Check if invoice # is found on sheet "Sales"
  i = 2
  Do Until Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value Then
      'Ask overwrite invoice #?
      If MsgBox("Invoice Number Already Used- Do you want to copy over?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Sales").Range("F:K")
  'Delete rows if invoice # is found
  Do Until Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value Then
      Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
      i = 1
    End If
    i = i + 2
  Loop
  ' Find first empty row in columns C:K on sheet Sales

    Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range A8:E27 on sheet Invoice
  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7:F27")
  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Sales
 For a = 2 To rng.Rows.count

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
      'Copy Invoice number
      Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value
      'Copy Date
      Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C3").Value
      'Copy Company name
      Sheets("Sales").Range("E" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C5").Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

END OF CODE:

My problem is that when I save each invoice I get all the blank lines in the invoice showing up as well:

[image]

Is there any way to change this so only the lines in the invoice that are used show up on the "Sales" Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the entire range of the invoice, just use the part you know has data:

```
With Sheets("Invoice")
    Dim lastRow as Long
    Dim rng as Range
    lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 6))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try- should I remove the part with the entire range or just add this to the current code. Not sure what it will do if I remove? Some parts of VBA code still elude me.

Comment: @Jen replace this line: `Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7:F27")` with my code. Then on your next line when you loop through `rng`, start at 1 instead of 2.

Comment: I have tried it . I am getting an error message at my a=2 line. I changed it to a=1 but that gives the same result. Thoughts?

Comment: @Jen what is the error message?

Comment: at first it was "duplicate declaration in current scope" I assumed because I had a dim rng as Range above so I made yours  rng1. Then the first part of the code worked and it checked for duplicate invoice numbers. but then hit a Run-time error '91':  Object variable or With Block variable not set. When I hit debug it highlighted my row "For a=2 To Rng.Rows.Count

Comment: @Jen Oh my bad, I missed your `Dim`s at the top of your code. Just make sure you only have one `Dim rng As Range` line, and continue to use `Rng` as the variable name.

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thanks so much for working through this for me. Learning lots. one more challenge to solve!!! Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Luu_HoaDon()
Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long

  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Kiêm tra só Hóa don có trong sheet "Sales"
  i = 2
  Do Until Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value Then
      'Hoi truóc khi ghi dè só Hóa don?
      If MsgBox("Trùng só Hóa don, Ban có ghi dè không?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Sales").Range("F:K")
  'Ghi dè néu trùng só Hóa don
  Do Until Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value Then
      Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
      i = 1
    End If
'    i = i + 2 '(chõ này nó cách 1 dòng tróng
    i = i + 1 'Thay 2 = 1 nó hét 1 dòng tróng
  Loop
  'Tìm dòng tróng côt C:K cua sheet Sales de ghi

    Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  '///////////////
  'Copy range A8:E27 on sheet Invoice
'  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7:F27")  'Thay dòng này bàng 5 dòng ké tiép

    With Sheets("Invoice")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 6))
    End With
'/////////////
  ' Copy Value tù Hóa don vào sheet Sales
 For a = 2 To rng.Rows.Count

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
      'Copy só Hóa don
      Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value
      'Copy Date
      Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C3").Value
      'Copy Company name
      Sheets("Sales").Range("E" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C5").Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation, and convert the code entirely to English?  Thanks.